# how to pass the complete event on (chnage) event bind with ng-select ? Angular 14

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I Front end Code

```
  <ng-select formControlName="constituencyId" placeholder="Select Constituency" (change)='onContituencyChanged($event)'>                    >
                                      <ng-option *ngFor="let op of this.getAllConsituencies"  
                                      [value]="op.id"
                                      [attr.typename]="op.constituencyTypeName" > 
                                      {{op.code}} {{op.name}}                              
                                    </ng-option>
                                    </ng-select>

                                    <label>Constituency Name</label>
```

Backend code

```
onContituencyChanged(evt: any) {
 
    console.log("targeted obj of constituency. " ,evt);
}
```

I'm just getting the value of the selected item rather than than a complete targeted event.

Actually I am using ng-select dropdown list in my angular I want two perfomr two operations firstly on change i want to get acces to the custom attribute added to the dropdown to perform some logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In ts:

```
myNgSelect: NgSelectComponent;


  @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) private set ngSelect(
    ngSelect: NgSelectComponent
  ) {
    if (!ngSelect) {
      return;
    }
    this.myNgSelect = ngSelect;
  }
```

Now, in your change event:

```
onContituencyChanged(evt: any) {
if (evt) {
      console.log('on myChange', this.myNgSelect.filterInput.nativeElement); //this defines your selected element's attributes.
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear thanks for replying but this didn't work for me. 
what does this line do? I dont have any input element (this.mySelectInputBox = ngSelect.filterInput.nativeElement; )

Comment: @HassanJavedSiddiqui, actually I tried the same in my code and just copied the same :). However, it has nothing to do with your code. I've edited my code. Just check if it works.